# How Can I Load Balance Outbound Email?

Tags: email, domain-name-system, exchange, email-server, spf

My server have four external IP address. 
I want to distribute to this IP addresses for sending emails.

For example :

1.st mail sending XX.XX.XX.10 ip

2.nd mail sending XX.XX.XX.11 ip

3.rd mail sending XX.XX.XX.12 ip

Because, i receive error message from hotmail. Block time is one day. But, second ip is clear.

Reason : Mail Server for hotmail.com could not accept your email at this time. MailEnable will keep trying to deliver this message and will notify you of any progress.

Comment: Do you send spam ?

Comment: I don't sending spam. I sending email only to my members. But 2000/3000 exceeds the number of sending e-mail hotmail is temporarily blocking the ip adress.

Comment: "load balancing"... sounds more like snowshoeing

Comment: pretty sure what you are trying to do violates hotmails terms of service. also are your "members" opt in?

Comment: Yes. My web site have a member form. Members is filling this form. this members    confirming activation email.
And "opt out link" included to all email

Comment: You send emails to __hotmail users__, or send emails to all users using __your hotmail account__ ?

Comment: See here for a real answer to your "problem":

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/695/how-to-avoid-hotmail-live-rejections-for-legit-large-volume-emailing

Answer (score 3):

This does not actually answers the question as you asked it, but anyway...

I think the "right" thing to do is not to try to circumvent hotmail block, but to understand **why** your emails get blocked and proceed from there. I presume you are not the only service in the world who needs to send lots of emails to hotmail users, and I presume all these services don't use such "hacker" techniques as your IP throttling. There should be some normal way.

Besides that, I think hotmail may be stupid but not dumb, and if you start sending those emails from multiple addresses, you may end-up with the whole subnet blocked permanently, or all emails with your service mentioned will go to "spam" folder.

Maybe right SPF records will help, also there's something called DMARC, try to google it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this.

Your Edge/HT server is responsible for sending emails out in Exchange 2007/2010. Emails can be sent out using either DNS or a SmartHost - but not both. You have to choose one of the mechanisms when you are configuring your outbound email.

If you are using SmartHost, your outbound mail is bound to a specific server.
If you are using DNS, the DNS mail delivery data will be pulled from the WAN connection of your firewall.

So unless you have a mechanism of changing your WAN Connection in your firewall depending on the DSN status codes from Hotmail, you cant do this.
IMHO.